# How to have a default value for datetime_field_tag in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to have a default value for `datetime_field_tag` in my view:

```
=form_tag form_path, method: :get do
  =label_tag :sign_up_at, 'Sign up before:'
  =date_field_tag :sign_up_at, (params[:sign_up_at] || 
                               Time.zone.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

  =label_tag :last_seen_at, 'Last seen after:'
  =datetime_field_tag :last_seen_at, (params[:last_seen_at] || 
                                     Time.zone.now.strftime("%d-%m-%YT%H:%M"))

  =submit_tag 'Filter', class: 'btn-info'
```

This results in having a `value` tag in HTML:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="last_seen_at" id="last_seen_at" value="22-05-2017T16:34">
```

[image: missing-default-value]

My guess is, I am having some kind of a problem with parsing `Time`. Can anyone help, please? Thanks!

Updated according to @deephak's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `today` which will give you just the `date` not time.

So, when you try to fetch time out of date rails will return `00:00`

**Example:**

```
Time.zone.today
#=> Mon, 22 May 2017

Time.zone.now
#=> Mon, 22 May 2017 09:34:57 EDT -04:00
```

To fix this, change

```
Time.zone.today.strftime("%d-%m-%YT%H:%M")
#=> "22-05-2017T00:00"
```

to

```
Time.zone.now.strftime("%d-%m-%YT%H:%M")
#=> "22-05-2017T09:33"

# OR

Time.current.strftime("%d-%m-%YT%H:%M")
#=> "22-05-2017T09:33"
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the incorrect time but still can't see the default value.

Comment: can you try with removing the `params[:last_seen_at]` once

Comment: Tried deleting the params like you suggested, but still can't see the default value in browser but only as a `value` tag.

Comment: Well it should work https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/datetime_field_tag

Comment: check if you are missing something

Comment: I did tried before, passing default value as `options` and later tried passing with `text_field_tag`, but still no luck. Weird...

Answer (score 6):

Just to supplement the other answer here: the `datetime_field_tag` helper is sensitive to the format of the datetime given to it. If, for example, the day, month, and year are in the wrong order, the value won't be displayed in the form input (and if you've got the developer console open, a warning message will be displayed).

It may depend on your locale, but the OP's `"%d-%m-%YT%H:%M"` format string has the year and day in reverse. `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"` seemed to fix it in my trials.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct, but if you would like to refactor this, you can setup a timeformat initializer.

config/time_formats.rb

```ruby
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:datetime_field] = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
```

Then when setting the value you can use:

```ruby
Time.zone.today.to_s(:datetime_field)
```

Remember to restart your `rails s` after changing the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
date_field_tag(:start_date, value = nil, options = {})
```

or if you want to submit onchange

```
date_select(:start_date, value = nil, options = {},onchange: "this.form.submit();")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try like rails, do like below.

```rb
    <%= datetime_field_tag 'start_at_update', Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00"), placeholder: '환율 기간(시작)', class: 'form-control w-50 d-inline-block h-auto w-auto ml-2 value-start-at_update', step: '1' %>
```